# React Redux API call, data not making it back to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

In the last couple of days I have been working on my Redux api call.  I am actually having a problem getting the data back to the view component.  Currently I'm able to see the data in the in the action generator, so I know at least I'm able to get it.  However, nothing is showing in the view.  I imagine it may have something to do with when it's loading.  This is why I tried to load it when the component is rendering.
https://djangoandreact.herokuapp.com/user/1 is what is not loading.

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zlor60q3jm?from-embed
Should be able to go to /user/1 at the end similar to going to /1 brings up an article(Tough Hope)

Heres the view component:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchUser } from "../store/actions/userActions";

class UserDetailView extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const userID = this.props.match.params.userID;
    fetchUser(userID); //fixed
  }
  render() {
    const { user } = this.props.user;
    console.log(user);

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{user.username}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  fetchUser: dispatch(fetchUser(ownProps.match.params.userID))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserDetailView);
```

Action generator

```
import axios from "axios";
import { thunk } from "react-redux";

export function fetchUser(userID) {
  console.log(userID);
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get(`/api/user/${userID}`).then(res => {
      dispatch(fetchUserSuccess(res.data));
      console.log(res.data); // loads data
    });
  };
}

// Handle HTTP errors since fetch won't.
function handleErrors(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }
  return response;
}

export const FETCH_USER_BEGIN = "FETCH_USER_BEGIN";
export const FETCH_USER_SUCCESS = "FETCH_USER_SUCCESS";
export const FETCH_USER_FAILURE = "FETCH_USER_FAILURE";

export const fetchUserBegin = () => ({
  type: FETCH_USER_BEGIN
});

export const fetchUserSuccess = user => ({
  type: FETCH_USER_SUCCESS,
  payload: { user }
});

export const fetchUserFailure = error => ({
  type: FETCH_USER_FAILURE,
  payload: { error }
});
```

Reducers(which are probably fine):

```
import {
  FETCH_USER_BEGIN,
  FETCH_USER_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_USER_FAILURE
} from "../actions/actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  user: {},
  loading: false,
  error: null
};

export default function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null
      };

    case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        user: action.payload.user
      };

    case FETCH_USER_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload.error,
        user: {}
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple fix would be change const {  user  } = this.props.user this line to const {  user  } = this.props; and also h3>{user && user.username}</h3>

Comment: user: {} is what i got back in the console after doing that.  I think I had that before, been all over the place with this one lol  For some reason I don't think it's making it out of the action generator, but it's tough to know for sure, I can't drop anymore console.logs in.

Comment: There are some weird usages in your app. First of all, you are using `mapDispatchToProps` somehow wrong. `fetchUser` property should be a function but instead, you are invoking `dispatch` immediately there. Also, why do you use `ownProps` there? Continuing, you are again using this action creator in your `componentDidMount` directly, not via the props. So, `fetchUser: id => dispatch( fetchUser( id ) )` then in `componentDidMount` use it like this: `this.props.fetchUser(userID)`.

Comment: With a simple setup, your code works for me, I test it with a fake fetch request. So, there should be another problem in your other parts of your code. If you can put your whole code into codesandbox.io, people can see it a little bit clear. Right now, I'm off to go sleep. In the daytime, if nobody looks, I try to check it. Good luck.

Comment: I forgot to mention. OP has a `user` state in the store where there is a `user` object in it :) So, actually `const { user } = this.props.user` is right.

Comment: Thanks  bud, hope to see you tomorrow.  Posting my codebin now

Comment: Oh my :) I couldn't figure out why and how at some point your app make hot reloading stops for me (with create-react-app).  So, I couldn't dig it very much. Maybe later. By the way, if you find out what causes this please let me know.

Comment: Running a Django backend and using rewired for ant. I'll drop that and it may come back

Answer (score 0):

folks.  I found it.

```
   case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        user: action.payload.user
      };
```

user is supposed to be  `user:action.payload`

Also, the user action was supposed to be

```
export const fetchUserSuccess = user => ({

    type: FETCH_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload:  user 
  })
```

WOOOOW.  But, honestly, I learned so much about Redux in the last two sleepless nights, it was worth the pain.  Really was.  Now, instead of copy pasta, I know what an action generator is and does, and reducer (obvi)